# how to tokenize String

Tags: java, regex

How can I change the following strings? I need to add spaces, for example:

- `"AnchorText"` to `"Anchor Text"`
- `"anchortext"` to `"anchor text"`

Comment: [String.split()?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I *tried* to edit the question, but Rasmey - you should add more details.

Comment: What? is there any logic? or you just need a hard code for particular String? "anchortext" to "anchor text".

Comment: @Kobi this isn't called tokenization. You are simply creating new strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
myString.replaceAll("(?i)(anchor)(text)", "$1 $2");
```

should work. That's not really tokenising, though.